# How to set onTouch for a layout(XML) that is added via inflation?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout-inflater

I'm trying to get control buttons to pop on/off screen when the screen is tapped. They will overlay a video. The problem I'm running in to is how to create a touch event for a layout that has been inflated.
The routine is as follows: 
1) set initial content to the video; 
2) inflate layout(XML), that contains the controls, over the top of the video; 
3)(NEED TO DO) create onTouch event for the newly inflated layout that hides/shows the buttons when the user taps the screen.

Layout containing the buttons to show/hide:

```
    <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/dpad_grid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnCount="3"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tiltUp"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/panRight"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tiltDown"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_down"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/panLeft"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"/>

    </GridLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zoomIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/zoom_in"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zoomOut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/zoom_out"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/zoomIn"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/irisDarker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/iris_darker"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/irisBrighter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/irisDarker"
        android:background="@drawable/iris_brighter"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/focusFar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dpad_grid"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/focus_far"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/focusNear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/focus_near"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/focusFar"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/irisBrighter"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/snapshot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/camera"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/focusFar"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gear"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code for adding the video and inflating the above layout:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();    

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        mv = new MjpegView(this);
        setContentView(mv);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        getWindow().addContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen2, null), relativeLayoutParams);
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: here's what I'm currently working with. Why does my code not get into the touch event when I touch the screen?

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        control_buttons = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen2, null);

        control_buttons.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            boolean gone = true;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                System.out.println("In OnTouch");

                if ( (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (gone == true) ){

                    getWindow().addContentView(control_buttons, relativeLayoutParams);

                    gone = false;
                    return true;
                }

                else if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (gone == false)) {
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    gone = true;
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: touch events? you mean MotionEvents (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)?

Comment: I don't think I need all the movements like swipe and what-not. I just want the buttons to show/hide when the user taps the screen.

Comment: have you read what inflater.inflate() returns?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it returns a View, right?

Comment: so what's the problem with attaching touch event listener to that View?

Comment: Well I have tried that and I haven't been able to get it to work. Largely in part because the Layout's button's click events are in this code section too so if there is no View for them I get a NPE. I'm not sure how to work around this...maybe separate the layout and the buttons and then set a touch event listener in the layout to show/hide the buttons? I don't know, any suggestions here would be great too.

Comment: @pskink I've added my current code with the touch listener if you wouldn't mind looking at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may work better for you. This will only work if the children in your RelativeLayout are either Buttons or GridLayouts that contain Buttons.

```
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourId);
    relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                for(int i = 0; i < relativeLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    if(relativeLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof Button) {
                        Button temp = (Button) relativeLayout.getChildAt(i);
                        if(temp.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                            temp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            temp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    } else if(relativeLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof GridLayout) {
                        GridLayout temp = (GridLayout) relativeLayout.getChildAt(i);
                        for(int g = 0; g < temp.getChildCount(); g++) {
                            Button tempButton = (Button) temp.getChildAt(g);
                            if(tempButton.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                                tempButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            } else {
                                temp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, check my EDIT above and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I just tried your code and it threw: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.GridLayout.setOnTouchListener

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work or not. I added an override to onInterceptTouchEvent()... The way I have implemented this type of thing in my own app is that I created a custom ViewGroup that extended GridLayout. Inside my CustomGridLayout.java file, I was able to easily override onInterceptTouchEvent() as well as onTouchEvent(). That way I could ensure that all touch events were handled by my custom ViewGroup first. I don't know if it is feasible for you to extend GridLayout just to make this work.

Comment: I actually just got your original code to work for the grid layout section, with a little tweaking. The problem is that that code doesn't work when I try to use it on the entire Relative Layout that the grid layout is contained in. My XML has more buttons than just the dpad that I need to show/hide. Do you have an equivalent example that would work for everything contained inside the Relative Layout? (And thanks for your help!)

Comment: Cool! I suppose you could try replacing GridLayout with RelativeLayout and put in the appropriate view ID. So `RelativeLayout allButtons = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourIdHere); I'm honestly not sure how many layers deep this trick will work but it's worth a try. I'm glad you could get part of it to work at least.

Comment: The problem with that is that GridLayout is not a button so it can't be processed through your For loop.

Comment: Ok check out my revised solution code. The code assumes that the children in your RelativeLayout are either Buttons or GridLayouts that contain Buttons. If you have other ViewGroups in there that contain Buttons, it should be easy enough to modify the code to accommodate that.

Comment: Thanks for the re-work. Unfortunately the methods getChildCount() and getChildAt() are not available to Views that have been inflated. Got any other ideas?